# Ensure that register is pushed to the stack at function entry

Tags: compilation, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

Typically, a C function is translated by clang for an ARM architecture in a way such that the LR register is pushed on the stack. However, if the function does not contain any function calls itself, LR is not pushed, i.e. the compiler assumes that LR won't be modified.

Is there a way to make the clang/llc always push LR at the beginning of a function, regardless of whether it calls a function or not?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a compiler flag to do that for you. If you're willing to modify the ARM backend, start from here: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ARMFrameLowering_8cpp_source.html#l01630

Comment: I am hoping for an attribute, pragma or annotation that does the trick.

Comment: One possibility is to add an empty inline asm at the beginning of the function that lists LR as a clobbered register.

Comment: How would that look like, i.e. how is the scope of such an inline asm statement defined?

Comment: Untested, but try sticking `asm volatile ( "" : : : "lr" );` at the beginning of the body of the function. This tells LLVM that `lr` gets clobbered, so it'll have to push the register in the prologue.

Comment: This has only an effect on the next statement but not on the entire function.

Comment: Not true. If LLVM finds that a register is clobbered *anywhere* in a function, it has to save that register at the beginning of the function.

Comment: You are right. Your solution works. If you would like to write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Alright, glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comments above.

Try sticking `asm volatile ( "" : : : "lr" );` at the beginning of the body of the function. This tells LLVM that `lr` gets clobbered. If LLVM finds that a register is clobbered anywhere in a function, it has to save that register at the beginning of the function.

(The somewhat cryptic inline asm syntax is documented here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)